# Can I subscribe to CAPI endpoint?

Tags: api, cloud-foundry

I need to build a dashboard application using capi API, my question is can I subscribe to capi endpoint and receive data continuously instead of sending requests to capi to get new data on every set intervals?

Answer (score 0):

No, not in the general sense. The Cloud Controller API works by sending a request and getting a response. Even the v3 API works this way.

The only exception is for obtaining logs, which isn't really CAPI, but that allows you to connect and stream logs and metrics via the firehose. The `cf` firehose plugin for the cf cli, allows you to play around what you can stream through the firehose.

https://plugins.cloudfoundry.org/#Firehose%20Plugin

Hope that helps!